# Error occurring while parsing files from awk

Tags: csv, awk

I have a CSV file and want to select a specific column of it. The problem is when I use {'print $1'}, it works. When I use {'print $2'}, the result is the remaining columns, not just column two. As an example:

file.csv:

```
1   2   3 
1   2   3 
1   2   3
```

codes:

```
awk '{print $1}':
1
1
1

awk '{print $2}':
2,3
2,3
2,3
```

Is my CSV file the source of the problem? What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Please wrap your samples in CODE TAGS `{}` button for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 2nd field print shows that your Input_file is having spaces and commas in it. So if this is the case then following may help.

```
awk -F'[ ,]' '{print $2}'  Input_file
```

Since you haven't mentioned any field separator for your Input_file so by default space is the field separator and then a line which is eg--> `1 2,3` 1st field will be `1` and 2nd field will be rest of the line in above code I have made 2 field separators space and comma and then printing 2nd field which is working fine only.